# php7 for imagecreatefromjpeg - Package 'php5-gd' has no installation candidate?

Tags: php-7, php-5.6, imagecreatefrompng

I am on php7 but I have a legacy program using:

```
imagecreatefromjpeg($filename)
```

So I tried to install:

```
$ sudo apt-get install php5-gd
```

No result:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package php5-gd is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'php5-gd' has no installation candidate
```

What should I install then instead for php7?

Or better, what should I replace `imagecreatefromjpeg` with?

Any ideas?

I have enabled `extension=php_gd2.dll` in my php.ini.

But I still get this error:

> Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function imagecreatefromjpeg() in
>   /var/w

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [PHP.net](http://php.net/manual/en/image.installation.php#120116)http://php.net/manual/en/image.installation.php#120116

`sudo apt-get install php7.0-gd`